# Can't declare "div" in enum

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, scope

I want to declare an enum with the basic math operations as the following:

```
enum Operations 
{
    div,
    mul,
    add,
    sub
};
```

but the compiler complains about this declaration as div is a reserved keyword in C++. How can I override it? or is there any solution?

Here is the error message:

> error: ‘div’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:158: error: previous declaration of ‘div_t div(int, int)’

Comment: Yep, changed in my comment.

Comment: This is not a C++ reserved keyword, it is a function identifier declared in <cstdlib>. Choose another name, like div_ or Div. You can #define div div_, but doing this you will lose access to the div function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div) is not a keyword, but rather a standard library function, declared in `stdlib.h` and possibly in `cstdlib`.

The simplest solution is to use different identifiers. Otherwise, you may use a scoped enumeration:

```
enum class Operations 
{
    div,
    mul,
    add,
    sub
};
```

This will put the enum's values in the `Operations` scope (`Operations::div`, `Operations::mul` etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Because `div` is a function declared in `cstdlib`, and the name of an unscoped enumeration may be omitted to global. This means you **cannot** use `div` as an enumeration.

in C++11, scoped enumeration is introduced for this situation

```
enum class Operations 
{
    div,
    mul,
    add,
    sub
};
```

and you can then use `Operations::div`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new namespace:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace a
{
    enum Operations
    {
        div,
        mul,
        add,
        sub
    };
}

int main()
{
    a::div;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: indenting?  I suggest using spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: there is a tab-to-space conversion on most code editors

Answer (score 0):

Use `cstdlib`, not `stdlib.h`, in C++.  And don't import the `std` namespace into the global namespace (ie, don't use `using namespace std`).  Then there will not be a `div` in the global namespace to collide with your `enum`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Unfortunately, `cstdlib` et al are allowed to bring names into the global namespace. This is bad, but it is the way it is.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I think I recall having noticed that in practice. It is bad, I would say it even stronger, it completely destroys the purpose of putting this stuff in the `std` namespace in the first place. Yes, you can refer to `std::div` if you like.  But you still cannot safely use any identifier unscoped in you program (for instance as name of a class or of a namespace) without checking that it does not clash with any name that might be introduced globally by some (recursively?) included header file.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It used to be "bad behaviour" pre C++11, and it is allowed since. But note that it only applies to the `csomething` headers with `something.h` equivalents in the C standard library. Most of the names are old and well known, and there are far fewer than in the C++ standard library.